# How to animate CAGradientLayer for a navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift

Our navigation bar uses CAGradientLayer to have a gradient effect. Now we want the gradient colour changing dynamically

We use the following code to achieve the gradient effect

```
let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        var updatedFrame = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.bounds
        updatedFrame.size.height += UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
        gradientLayer.frame = updatedFrame
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor] // start color and end color

        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0) // Horizontal gradient start
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0) // Horizontal gradient end

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(gradientLayer.bounds.size)
        gradientLayer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(image, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```

We tried to add animation on this layer, but it doesn't work

```
 let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
        animation.fromValue = [0,0.5]
        animation.toValue = [0,0.9]
        animation.autoreverses = true
        animation.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        gradientLayer.add(animation,forKey: nil)
```

I noticed that this way of setting the gradient colour is actually setting a background image. I think this is the reason why the animation doesn't work as setting image is an atomic action.

I searched for other ways to set the gradient effect but had no luck.  So is it possible to implement the gradient effect animation on the navigation bar?

Comment: I don't think It is possible. As you said and as I know, It just puts an image to make gradient affect.

Answer (score 0):

I still didn't find a way to animate the CAGradientLayer of a navigation bar. However, if you just want to simply add animation on the navigation bar without caring whether it is really a part of the navigation bar, I found a workaround.

Instead of changing the navigation bar's layer, I put a UIView whose layer has gradient animation behind the navigation bar.

```
// create a view
// set its size the same as the navigation bar
let gradientView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.width,height:(self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height+UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height)))
view.addSubview(gradientView)

// add animation on this view
let anAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
anAnimation.duration = 1.5;
anAnimation.repeatCount = 1;
anAnimation.autoreverses = false;
animation.fromValue = [0,0.5]
animation.toValue = [0,0.9]
gradientView.layer.add(anAnimation,forKey: "backgroundColor")

// hide the navigation bar's background image
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

It works as if you add the animation on the navigation bar (which is actually not).